# google colab - Download files synchronously

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am using this code snippet to download files from google colab:

```
from google.colab import files
files.download("sample_data/california_housing_train.csv")
print("done")
```

But the output is

```
done
Downloading "california_housing_train.csv"
```

The download function is asynchronous. This may not seem much but actually the function is being run in a loop so after starting download some external libraries are called in starting of next iteration and it clears the output. Also, I have tested it many times that in case the output is cleared before the file is downloaded, it will not download.

Also, please dont suggest downloading it from the file menu. There are going to be a lot of files so it has to be programmatically. Also, please dont suggest the method to zip it programmatically and then download it from file browser, as i have to download the files after each iteration bcz I am using a workaround for colab's "are you still there" but it stills considers my session idle and deleted runtime and all the files are lost.

Thank you in advance. Sorry for any grammatical errors.

Edit:

I have also tried using sleep method but that didn't work as sometimes the files take more time to load despite very very good internet connection compared to the size of the file. Keeping very high values of sleep() is not good as it is not the best way. still, if i find nothing else i will use sleep() only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I found a temporary workaround which is not wholly programmable and may need manual downloading in cases where runtime gets deleted due to inactivity before executing whole program.

So, my idea is to mount google drive on the runtime and copy the files to a folder in google drive after each execution. In the end zip the folder in drive and download it by `files.download(path to drive zip)` . In case the runtime was not able to execute whole code and dies prematurely, the folder in the google drive will remain unlike it being deleted when runtime is destroyed, so we can go and manually download the folder from google drive.

If anyone else has a better solution, please let me know.